Script variable won't send to Telegram
I have a workflow which posts an article to Dev.to and receives a URL in return.
I am trying to pass the URL inside a message bound to Telegram, the variable does populate with the correct URL.
Yet I cannot seem to pass the URL to the message itself. it comes up empty:
New articles published on dev.to:'\n'
Here is the relevant code:
          # Send the POST request to dev.to and capture the response
          response=$(curl -s -X POST "https://dev.to/api/articles" \
            -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
            -H "api-key: $DEVTO_TOKEN" \
            -d "$JSON_PAYLOAD")
          
          # Extract the article URL from the response
          ARTICLE_URL=$(echo "$response" | jq -r '.url')
          echo "Article URL: $ARTICLE_URL"

          # Append the result to summary and URLs list
          result_summary+="Processed article: $TITLE - $ARTICLE_URL"$'\n'
          article_urls+="$ARTICLE_URL\n"
        done

        # Output the summary and URLs for use in the next step
        echo "::set-output name=result_summary::$result_summary"
        echo "::set-output name=article_urls::$article_urls"
      
    - name: Send Telegram message
      if: success()
      run: |
        ARTICLE_URLS=$(echo "${{ steps.publish_articles.outputs.article_urls }}" | tr '\n' ' ')  # Replace newlines with spaces
        MESSAGE="New articles published on dev.to:\n${ARTICLE_URLS}"

        curl -s -X POST "https://api.telegram.org/bot${TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN}/sendMessage" \
          -d "chat_id=${TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID}" \
          -d "text=${MESSAGE}"

    - uses: actions-ecosystem/action-create-comment@v1
      if: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' }}
      with:
        github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        body: |
          Articles processed in this pull request:
          ```
          ${{ steps.publish_articles.outputs.result_summary }}
          ```

I tried changing the variable formatting to:

MESSAGE="New articles published on dev.to:\n${ARTICLE_URLS}"
MESSAGE="New articles published on dev.to:\n$ARTICLE_URLS"
MESSAGE="New articles published on dev.to:\n$(ARTICLE_URLS)"



Don't use set-output, use the $GITHUB_OUTPUT environment file. 2. You're trying to set a multi-line output; you need to use heredoc syntax for that.

